# JellyException: Could not parse Jelly script : null

Tags: jenkins, jelly, jenkins-email-ext

I'm trying to configure some features in Jenkins for our project. In the process of configuring Editable Email Notification, I have created a new jelly script file in `$JENKINS_HOME/email-templates` folder as shown here

```
   <j:choose>
      <j:when test="${build.result=='SUCCESS'}">
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/test1.gif" />
      </j:when>
      <j:when test="${build.result=='FAILURE'}">
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/red.gif" />
      </j:when>
      <j:otherwise>
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/yellow.gif" />
      </j:otherwise>
    </j:choose>
```

and accessing it in Jenkins config like this

```
${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="groovy-html"}
```

When I build the job, with these setting, I'm getting email with the content
 `"JellyException: Could not parse Jelly script : null"`

Please find below script jelly script.

Thanks in advance!!

```html
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#38;#38;nbsp&#59;">
]>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define">

<STYLE>
BODY, TABLE, TD, TH, P {
  font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,sans serif;
  font-size:11px;
  color:black;
}
h1 { color:black; }
h2 { color:black; }
h3 { color:black; }
TD.bg1 { color:white; background-color:#0000C0; font-size:120% }
TD.bg2 { color:white; background-color:#4040FF; font-size:110% }
TD.bg3 { color:white; background-color:#8080FF; }
TD.test_passed { color:blue; }
TD.test_failed { color:red; }
TD.console { font-family:Courier New; }
</STYLE>
<BODY>


<!-- GENERAL INFO -->

<TABLE>
  <TR><TD align="right">
    <j:choose>
      <j:when test="${build.result=='SUCCESS'}">
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/test1.gif" />
      </j:when>
   <j:when test="${build.result=='FAILURE'}">
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/red.gif" />
      </j:when>
      <j:otherwise>
        <IMG SRC="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/yellow.gif" />
      </j:otherwise>
    </j:choose>
  </TD><TD valign="center"><B style="font-size: 200%;">QTP Execution - ${build.result}</B></TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Execution URL</TD><TD><A href="${rooturl}${build.url}">${rooturl}${build.url}</A></TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Project:</TD><TD>${project.name}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Date of Execution:</TD><TD>${it.timestampString}</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>Execution duration:</TD><TD>${build.durationString}</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<BR/>


<!-- CHANGE SET -->

<j:set var="changeSet" value="${build.changeSet}" />
<j:if test="${changeSet!=null}">
  <j:set var="hadChanges" value="false" />
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>CHANGES</B></TD></TR>
    <j:forEach var="cs" items="${changeSet}" varStatus="loop">
      <j:set var="hadChanges" value="true" />
      <j:set var="aUser" value="${cs.hudsonUser}"/>
      <TR>
        <TD colspan="2" class="bg2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Revision <B>${cs.commitId?:cs.revision?:cs.changeNumber}</B> by
          <B>${aUser!=null?aUser.displayName:cs.author.displayName}: </B>
          <B>(${cs.msgAnnotated})</B>
         </TD>
      </TR>
      <j:forEach var="p" items="${cs.affectedFiles}">
        <TR>
          <TD width="10%">&nbsp;&nbsp;${p.editType.name}</TD>
          <TD>${p.path}</TD>
        </TR>
      </j:forEach>
    </j:forEach>
    <j:if test="${!hadChanges}">
      <TR><TD colspan="2">No Changes</TD></TR>
    </j:if>
  </TABLE>
<BR/>
</j:if>


<!-- ARTIFACTS -->

<j:set var="artifacts" value="${build.artifacts}" />
<j:if test="${artifacts!=null and artifacts.size()&gt;0}">
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1"><B>LOG FILES</B></TD></TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <j:forEach var="f" items="${artifacts}">
         <li>
           <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}artifact/${f}">${f}</a>
         </li>
       </j:forEach>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
<BR/>  
</j:if>


<!-- Email Content -->

<TABLE width="100%">
  <TR><TD align="right">
    <j:choose>
      <j:when test="${build.result=='SUCCESS'}">  
   <TR><TD class="bg1"><B>Please find attached FIle Differences sheet and Logs. If there are any unexpected file differences then please investigate further.</B></TD></TR>
      </j:when>
   <j:when test="${build.result=='FAILURE'}">
        <TR><TD class="bg1"><B>Something went wrong. Please check log file for more details and if required then restart the execution after making appropriate changes.</B></TD></TR>
      </j:when>
      <j:otherwise>
        <TR><TD class="bg1"><B>Please contact Jenkins Administrator.</B></TD></TR>
      </j:otherwise>
    </j:choose>
</TABLE>
<BR/>

<!-- MAVEN ARTIFACTS -->

<j:set var="mbuilds" value="${build.moduleBuilds}" />
<j:if test="${mbuilds!=null}">
  <TABLE width="100%">
      <TR><TD class="bg1"><B>BUILD ARTIFACTS</B></TD></TR>
      <j:forEach var="m" items="${mbuilds}">
        <TR><TD class="bg2"><B>${m.key.displayName}</B></TD></TR>
        <j:forEach var="mvnbld" items="${m.value}">
        <j:set var="artifacts" value="${mvnbld.artifacts}" />
        <j:if test="${artifacts!=null and artifacts.size()&gt;0}">
      <TR>
        <TD>
         <j:forEach var="f" items="${artifacts}">
           <li>
             <a href="${rooturl}${mvnbld.url}artifact/${f}">${f}</a>
           </li>
         </j:forEach>
       </TD>
      </TR>
        </j:if>
        </j:forEach>
      </j:forEach>
  </TABLE>
<BR/>  
</j:if>


<!-- JUnit TEMPLATE -->

<j:set var="junitResultList" value="${it.JUnitTestResult}" />
<j:if test="${junitResultList.isEmpty()!=true}">
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>JUnit Tests</B></TD></TR>
    <j:forEach var="junitResult" items="${it.JUnitTestResult}">
      <j:forEach var="packageResult" items="${junitResult.getChildren()}">
        <TR><TD class="bg2" colspan="2"> Name: ${packageResult.getName()} Failed: ${packageResult.getFailCount()} test(s), Passed: ${packageResult.getPassCount()} test(s), Skipped: ${packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s), Total: ${packageResult.getPassCount()+packageResult.getFailCount()+packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s)</TD></TR>
        <j:forEach var="failed_test" items="${packageResult.getFailedTests()}">
          <TR bgcolor="white"><TD class="test_failed" colspan="2"><B><li>Failed: ${failed_test.getFullName()} </li></B></TD></TR>
        </j:forEach>
      </j:forEach> 
    </j:forEach>  
  </TABLE> 
<BR/>
</j:if>


<!-- COBERTURA TEMPLATE -->

<j:set var="coberturaAction" value="${it.coberturaAction}" />
<j:if test="${coberturaAction!=null}">
  <j:set var="coberturaResult" value="${coberturaAction.result}" />
  <j:if test="${coberturaResult!=null}">
   <table width="100%"><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>Cobertura Report</B></TD></table>
 <table width="100%"><TD class="bg2" colspan="2"><B>Project Coverage Summary</B></TD></table>
            <table border="1px" class="pane">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <j:forEach var="metric" items="${coberturaResult.metrics}">
                        <td>${metric.name}</td>
                    </j:forEach>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>${coberturaResult.name}</td>
                    <j:forEach var="metric" items="${coberturaResult.metrics}">
                        <td data="${coberturaResult.getCoverage(metric).percentageFloat}">${coberturaResult.getCoverage(metric).percentage}%
                            (${coberturaResult.getCoverage(metric)})
                        </td>
                    </j:forEach>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <j:if test="${coberturaResult.sourceCodeLevel}">
                <h2>Source</h2>
                <j:choose>
                    <j:when test="${coberturaResult.sourceFileAvailable}">
                        <div style="overflow-x:scroll;">
                            <table class="source">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3">${coberturaResult.relativeSourcePath}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                ${coberturaResult.sourceFileContent}

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </j:when>
                    <j:otherwise>
                        <p>
                            <i>Source code is unavailable</i>
                        </p>
                    </j:otherwise>
                </j:choose>
            </j:if>

            <j:forEach var="element" items="${coberturaResult.childElements}">
                <j:set var="childMetrics" value="${coberturaResult.getChildMetrics(element)}"/>
               <table width="100%"><TD class="bg2" colspan="2">Coverage Breakdown by ${element.displayName}</TD></table>
                <table border="1px" class="pane sortable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <j:forEach var="metric" items="${childMetrics}">
                            <td>${metric.name}</td>
                        </j:forEach>
                    </tr>
                    <j:forEach var="c" items="${coberturaResult.children}">
                        <j:set var="child" value="${coberturaResult.getChild(c)}"/>
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                ${child.xmlTransform(child.name)}
                            </td>
                            <j:forEach var="metric" items="${childMetrics}">
                                <j:set var="childResult" value="${child.getCoverage(metric)}"/>
                                <j:choose>
                                    <j:when test="${childResult!=null}">
                                        <td data="${childResult.percentageFloat}">${childResult.percentage}%
                                            (${childResult})
                                        </td>
                                    </j:when>
                                    <j:otherwise>
                                        <td data="101">N/A</td>
                                    </j:otherwise>
                                </j:choose>
                            </j:forEach>
                        </tr>
                    </j:forEach>
                </table>
            </j:forEach>
  </j:if>
<BR/>
</j:if>


<!-- CONSOLE OUTPUT -->

<j:getStatic var="resultFailure" field="FAILURE" className="hudson.model.Result"/>
<j:if test="${build.result==resultFailure}">
<TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<TR><TD class="bg1"><B>CONSOLE OUTPUT</B></TD></TR>
<j:forEach var="line" items="${build.getLog(100)}"><TR><TD class="console">${line}</TD></TR></j:forEach>
</TABLE>
<BR/>
</j:if>

</BODY>
</j:jelly>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the images... I, however, advise you to use formatted text to show code and/or error messages - it is more readable and helpful for us.

Comment: I have updated my post just now.